# Custom font not working in canvas

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, canvas

I am using Bootstrap 3. I added this to my custom css:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'My font';
    src: url('../fonts/myfont.ttf') format('ttf');
}
```

myfont.tff is a custom font.

Then I try to use this font in a canvas:

`context.font = '40pt My font';`

But another font is displayed. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
src: url('../fonts/myfont.ttf')  format('truetype');
```

**Usage:**

```
body {
font-family: 'MyFontFamily', myfont;
}
```